# Disabling or changing a feature during a drag or resize

Tags: javascript, css, drag-and-drop

My question is not about implementation, but I am wondering if anyone knows of a GUI feature which detects when a user resizes a window or drags it across the desktop, and turns off a certain feature while the user is making that change.

For example, you're watching a video, you drag it across the screen, and while this is happening, the frame rate of the video is reduced, then returned to its previous level once you're done dragging.

Another example might be, you're resizing and dragging a window, and the window becomes semi-transparent while this is happening, so you can see what is behind the window, then the window becomes opaque once in its new position.

My question is whether some feature like that exists- I thought Windows had something like the second example- somewhere, and if so, what the name of that feature is, or where I might find some documentation on it.

Again, the critical aspect is that the feature turn off or change somehow in response to resizing/dragging, and then return to its previous state.

Any ideas are much appreciated.  If any part of this question is unclear, I will gladly clarify.

Comment: this is the so called `event handling` IMHO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check here to see [all events that you can track with JS](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_events.html).
You can also define [custom events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events).

Comment: Thanks.  "Event handling" is broadly the term I was looking for.